# DJANGO oauth2 grant_type client_credentials

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, client, access-token

I have implemented oauth2 using client_credentials gran_type. While generating access token(using o/token/ api) user id is not linked with access_token model , user field is null. so I'm not able to access any  other api's using access token getting 403 forbidden error.

Any suggestion and help would be appreciable.

Comment: If you are trying to generate token using username and password use grant_type `password`.

Comment: @ParasJain I'm using grant type as client_credentials, I don't want password grant type

Comment: Client credentials grant type won't associate the user with the token. Refer : https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client credentials grant type is used by the client to access the server resources using client ID and client secret but NOT on behalf of any users. The tokens generated are for different devices that are running the client application and have nothing to do with the user of the application. For User Authentication you must use `password` or `convert_token` grant type as suitable.

Read about client credentials at 
http://oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials